# Resize selected shapes powerpoint VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm creating macro which should resize selected shapes. I've created with loop, so input box will pop up for each shape, and this works fine but problem is that this not changing anything. Any suggestions why?

Thank you so much.

Regards!

Sub resize()

```
Dim objHeigh As Integer
Dim objWidth As Integer
Dim oSh As Shape


On Error GoTo CheckErrors

With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
    If .Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "You need to select a shape first"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With

For Each oSh In ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange

    objHeigh = oSh.Height
    objWidth = oSh.Width

    objHeigh = InputBox$("Assign a new size of Height", "Heigh", objHeigh)
         ' give the user a way out
    If objName = "QUIT" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If objName <> "" Then
        oSh.Name = objName
    End If
Next

 objWidth = InputBox$("Assign a new size of Width", "Width", objWidth)
         ' give the user a way out
    If objName = "QUIT" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If objName <> "" Then
        oSh.Name = objName
    End If


Exit Sub
```

CheckErrors:
        MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason nothing happens, is that you do random things with your variables.

Following code is going to fix that:

```
    Sub test()

Dim objHeigh As Integer
Dim objWidth As Integer
Dim oSh As Shape


On Error GoTo CheckErrors

With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
    If .Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "You need to select a shape first"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With

For Each oSh In ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange

    objHeigh = oSh.Height
    objWidth = oSh.Width

    objHeigh = CInt(InputBox$("Assign a new size of Height", "Heigh", objHeigh))
         ' give the user a way out
    If objHeigh = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If objName <> "" Then
        oSh.Name = objName
    End If


 objWidth = CInt(InputBox$("Assign a new size of Width", "Width", objWidth))
         ' give the user a way out
    If objWidth = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If


oSh.Height = CInt(objHeigh)
oSh.Width = CInt(objWidth)
Next
Exit Sub

CheckErrors: MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```

EDIT: Updateed code with an Cast to Int. Type mismatch sould be gone

EDIT2: Some more Fixes. This solution works as intended on my machine

Comment: Now Im getting an error when I want to insert Heigh, it says "Type mismatch"... :/ but Im sure I have entered integer value.

Comment: I'm afraid it's still same... :(

Comment: @Norby My mistake. Try again please. I have updated the code to meke it work on my machine

Comment: Great, thank you. This works good. Do you maybe know how can I convert Integer to cm, because in ppt size is in centimeters?

Comment: Powerpoints default DPI are set to 96. So your Formula goes `centimeters = pixels * 2.54 / 96` and vice versa.

Comment: 1) You should use Single rather than Integer and 2) PowerPoint's units are in points, not pixels or centimeters; 72 points to the inch, so if the user is entering width and height in inches, multiply by 72. If they're entering cm, then multiply by 72*2.54

Comment: Thank you very much for help :)

Comment: Answer marked. Can you please help me little more about converting inserted number, it should be as in tab Format>Size? If you want I can open new question? Thanks